# Determining when layer has been loaded in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcobjects, layers

Is there an event in ArcObjects to determine whether a layer (specifically a shapefile) has been loaded into a map?

I'm using ArcObjects 10.4.1 and C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event handler for capturing layers added to the map is [IActiveViewEvents.ItemAdded](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IActiveViewEvents_ItemAdded.htm)

Make sure its pointing to a Map and not PageLayout.

You would then test to see if it is specifically a shapefile.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The object of capturing this event is to rebuild feature cache. My code is now capturing properly both ItemDeleted and ItemAdded events. Now with the later, i'm losing feature cache even though I'm calling the same method for both events. Is there another event handler being called after ItemAdded that might be forcing to lose feature cache again?

Comment: No idea and without seeing the code I can't really comment, are you talking about this form of [cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#EnableDisplayCaching.htm)?

Comment: I mean [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMapCache.htm)
To rebuild cache I'm using BuildCache method. I can post code if it does help.

Comment: In the remarks section of the link you supplied it explicitly states caches are not supported for shapefiles, may be that is your issue?

Comment: That is not the issue, but thank you anyway. I'll open a new question detailing my problem in a clearer way in case I need

Answer (score 3):

Here is some boiler plate code to set up active view events. You'll just need to write a function that checks if the item added is a shapefile. Call that function from Events_ItemAdded().

```c#
    public static IActiveViewEvents_Event ActiveViewEvent;    

    private void WireDocumentEvents()
    {
        // Event handlers
        ArcMap.Events.CloseDocument += new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_CloseDocumentEventHandler(Events_CloseDocument);

        if (ActiveViewEvent == null)
            ActiveViewEvent = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap as IActiveViewEvents_Event;

        if (ActiveViewEvent == null) return;

        ActiveViewEvent.ItemAdded += Events_ItemAdded;
        ActiveViewEvent.ItemDeleted += Events_ItemRemoved;
    }

    private void UnWireDocumentEvents()
    {
        // Unload Event handlers
        ArcMap.Events.CloseDocument -= new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_CloseDocumentEventHandler(Events_CloseDocument);

        if (ActiveViewEvent == null) return;

        ActiveViewEvent.ItemAdded -= Events_ItemAdded;
        ActiveViewEvent.ItemDeleted -= Events_ItemRemoved;

        ActiveViewEvent = null;
    }

    void Events_CloseDocument()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING WHEN DOCUMENT CLOSES
    }

    private void Events_ItemAdded(object item)
    {
       //DO SOMETHING WHEN ITEM ADDED
    }

    private void Events_ItemRemoved(object item)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING WHEN ITEM REMOVED
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up code... +1 from me

Comment: I think more code might be needed to handle when dataframes are added, removed, switched.